# Removing single elements of svg in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code in d3.js

```
var svg = d3.select(".Canvas").append("svg").attr(
            "width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
            height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr(
            "transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
            "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxisMajor).append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6).attr("dy",
                    ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end");
```

I tried the following to remove only the y-axis, not the whole svg:

d3.select(".Canvas").selectAll("svg").selectAll("g").select(".y axis").remove();

Why is the code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you set class attribute as `y axis` , you actually set two classes. So in order to select and match both class names you need to call `select` with `.y.axis`. So that the result should be:

```
d3.select(".canvas").selectAll("svg").selectAll("g").select(".y.axis").remove();
```

at least worked for me, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7ztD/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tUZ45/) with a couple of simple ways to do it (see my comments in the fiddle).

```
d3.select("svg > g > #the_one_circle")
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("r",1)
    .remove();
```

Note how the `svg` and `g` elements are still there after removing the circle.